# phpからmysqlへの接続

Tags: php, mysql

php→mysqlへ接続ができず非常に困っています。
PHPのコードは以下になります。

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','ユーザ名','ホスト名');

if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die('Connect Error('.$mysqli->connect_errno.')'.$mysqli->connect_error);
}else{
    echo "接続成功";
}
?>
```

上記コードで試すとWarning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'ユーザ名'@'localhost' (using password: YES) というエラーが発生します。
調べるとユーザ名かエラー名が間違っている際にこのエラーが発生すると記載があったので、DBからユーザ名、パスワードまで全て作り直して再度トライしたのですが、このエラーから抜け出せません。

ちなみに、パスワード名を空にすると接続成功になります。
もう長い間解決策を探し続けているのですが見つからず、、、どなたか教えていただければ大変助かります。

宜しくお願いします。

※※※
コメント有難うございました！
先ほどphpmyadminをいじっていたら、PW有りで接続できました。
恐らく、ターミナル内ではなくphpmyadmin内でユーザ名、PW名を作成していなかったことが原因だと思います。

ただ、データベースへの接続はできたのですが、DBの選択ができません。
phpmyadmin内でDBを作成したのですが、php外部ファイルから指定するとエラーが起こります。
すみません、初心者なのでうまく説明できませんが、、、

Comment: `mysqli`の3つめのパラメータが「ホスト名」になっているのは意図通りでしょうか、誤記でしょうか。「パスワード名を空にすると･･･」はパスワードの誤記でしょうか、それともホスト名やユーザー名の誤記でしょうか。あと、ユーザーを作り直した手順も具体的に記載してあると良いです。(コメントではなく質問を編集して訂正/追記してください)